# How does AWS S3 store files? (directory structure)

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

We are in the dev phase. We were planning to use a dedicated infrastcrutre but swapped the decision to AWS cloud.

The directory structure regarding uploaded images was implemented like:

> web_root\{year}\{month}\{day}\{type}_{filename_md5_hash}.jpeg

Where the type is either `s` for small image or `o` for original size. The small image is created using a filter.

The problem is that I heard AWS S3 doesn't give you control over the directory structure inside a bucket.

Your invaluable explanations were always of great help. Thanks

Comment: You already have some good answers here so another one might be redundant,  but the thing about S3 is that folders are emulated by `/` in the object key (= "path").  You upload an object "into" a folder over the API by simply putting slashes in its name.  There is no need to create the folders, they just exist whenever the files exist.  It's possible, in the console, or by creating empty objects with `/` as the last character, but it is completely unnecessary.  There is no real hierarchy, so there is no limit or performance considerations for the number of files "in" a folder.  Play with it.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is covered in the AWS S3 documentation:

[Working with Folders](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/FolderOperations.html)

> In Amazon S3, buckets and objects are the primary resources, where objects are stored in buckets. **Amazon S3 has a flat structure with no hierarchy like you would see in a typical file system**. However, for the sake of organizational simplicity, **the Amazon S3 console supports the folder concept as a means of grouping objects**. Amazon S3 does this by using key name prefixes for objects.
>
> For example, you can create a folder in the console called `photos`, and store an object called `myphoto.jpg` in it.  The object is then stored with the key name `photos/myphoto.jpg`, where `photos/` is the prefix.
>
> ...
>
> **You can have folders within folders**, but not buckets within buckets. **You can upload and copy objects directly into a folder**. Folders can be created, deleted, and made public, but they cannot be renamed. Objects can be moved from one folder to another.

So, you can indeed upload files to S3 using a similar folder structure in your bucket:

`http://{bucket}.{endpoint}.amazonaws.com/web_root/{year}/{month}/{day}/{type}_{filename_md5_hash}.jpeg`

Or

`http://{endpoint}.amazonaws.com/{bucket}/web_root/{year}/{month}/{day}/{type}_{filename_md5_hash}.jpeg`

Comment: Thank you sir for this explanation.

Comment: Can you expand on why this is? Is there some sort of performance benefit to using a flat structure?

Comment: @PrithviBoinpally flat environment enables you to scale quickly, even for petabyte or exabyte loads.

Answer (score 3):

S3 isn't a normal filesystem and it doesn't have a file structure as such but it does have nested keys for the object references and even kind of pretends that it's filesystem like with the API (you use `aws s3 ls` to list a bucket and then kep using it as you move through the object tree much like you might with a file system).

So if you want to create an object called `foo_ashdbasd.jpeg` and normally you'd want that to sit in a folder structure like this `web_root\2016\06\15` then you simply write to an object in your S3 bucket called `web_root/2016/06/15/foo_ashdbasd.jpeg`.