# How to download multiple files having same prefix as filename from various folders of S3 bucket?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, awss3transfermanager

Let's say that I have an S3 bucket named `bucketSample`.

And I have different folders like `abc`,`def` and `xyz`.

Now I have multiple files having prefix `hij_` in all the above mentioned folders.

I want to download all the files having prefix `hij_`. (For Example, `hij_qwe.txt`,`hij_rty.pdf`,etc)

I have gone through various ways but for `GetObject` I have to provide specific object names and I only know the prefix.

And using TransferManager I can download all files of folder `abc` but not the files with the specific prefix only.

So is there any way that I can only download all the files with prefix `hij_`?

Comment: If you are using TransferManager's downloadDirectory() method, then you should be able to set the keyPrefix to abc/hij_ and it will download all objects with that key prefix. The key prefix doesn't have to end with the folder name (S3 is not a regular hierarchical file system with folders and files).

Comment: Thanks a lot @jarmod, it worked.
But it also creates the same hierarchy abc/hij_ , but can I download only the files without the hierarchy(folder structure), as my abc folder is situated too deep in the hierarchy like (bucket/qwe/rty/uio/.../abc), please let me know if there is any way I can achieve that.

Comment: You can specify a local destinationDirectory but TransferManager will, I believe, always create subfolders based on your key hierarchy. Nothing else would make sense. You can move the files afterwards, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void getFiles(final Set<String> bucketName, final Set<String> keys, final Set<String> prefixes) {
    try {
        ObjectListing objectListing = s3Client.listObjects(bucketName); //lists all the objects in the bucket
        while (true) {
            for (Iterator<?> iterator = objectListing.getObjectSummaries().iterator();
                 iterator.hasNext(); ) {
                S3ObjectSummary summary = (S3ObjectSummary) iterator.next();
                for (String key : keys) {
                    for (String prefix : prefixes)
                        if (summary.getKey().startsWith(key + "/" prefix)) {
                            //HERE YOU CAN GET THE FULL KEY NAME AND HENCE DOWNLOAD IT IN NEW FILE USING THE TRANFER MANAGER
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (objectListing.isTruncated()) {
                objectListing = s3Client.listNextBatchOfObjects(objectListing);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (AmazonServiceException e) { }
}
```

Read about the AWS Directory Structure in here : [How does AWS S3 store files? (directory structure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37846980/how-does-aws-s3-store-files-directory-structure)

Therefore, for your use case key + "/" + prefix acts as the prefix of the objects stored in the S3 bucket. By comparing the prefix will all the objects in the S3 Bucket, you can get the full key name.

Comment: what do you mean by `key` here? `accesskey` or `secretkey`?

Answer (score 0):

With python you can use boto3 library which I found very useful for solving a similar case.

Sample code:

```python
import boto3
import os

KEY = ''
SECRET = ''
download_folder = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Downloads')
bucket = 'bucketSample'
folders = ['abc', 'def', 'xyz']
prefixes = ['hij_']

try:
    # Needed for the pagination method in order to get objects with certain prefixes instead of iterating over all objects, you should get the aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key for your bucket if available
    s3 = boto3.resource(
        's3',
        aws_access_key_id=KEY,
        aws_secret_access_key=SECRET)

    # Needed for the download method, you should get the aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key for your bucket if available
    client = boto3.client(
        's3',
        aws_access_key_id=KEY,
        aws_secret_access_key=SECRET)

    # Get paginated objects
    paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects')

    for folder in folders:
        for file_prefix in prefixes:
            prefix = folder + file_prefix
            page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix)

            if page_iterator:
                for page in page_iterator:
                    if 'Contents' in page:
                        for content in page['Contents']:
                            file_path = os.path.join(download_folder, content['Key'])
                            s3.meta.client.download_file(bucket, str(content['Key']), file_path)
except:
    print('An error occurred')
```